# Color fill cells if it contains a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of cells that contain 1 of 12 values. I have 4 different colors that I want the the cell filled depending on the cell value. How do I do this? 
We are running Excel Professional 2010
Del

Comment: Look up "Conditional Formatting".

Answer (score 1):

You should use Conditional Formatting.

To set it up, go to Home > Conditional Formatting (this is in the Styles section) > Highlight Cells Rules > Equal To.

Then enter the value you wish, and the colour the cell should go.  If none of the presets are good enough, you can use the Custom Format option.  Just remember when dealing with cell colour you should look in the Fill tab.